# Send email via wp-mail not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in wordpress. I am sending mail via wp-mail function locally I have install east wp-mail plugin for smtp.

```
include("wp-mail.php");
$to = 'test@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Apple Computer';
$message = 'Steve, I think this computer thing might really take off.';

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
```

But I am getting error liike :

> Slow down cowboy, no need to check for new mails so often!

**Please guide me....**

Do i need to change in any file or install any plugin ???

Comment: Are you executing WordPress on localhost?

Comment: yes i am running my project locally...

Answer (score 3):

`wp_mail` works similar to PHP's function `mail`. You can read more about it [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/). PHP `mail` function needs access to `sendmail` binary, as stated in [docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mail.requirements.php), you shouldn't have this configured in localhost, that's why it fails to send emails.

In order to send emails when testing your site in localhost you should configure SMTP to send emails.

There's a pretty good plugin called WP Mail SMTP, you can install it [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/).

It overrides the `wp_mail` function and enables you to send emails using the Gmail SMTP server, for instance. You can use any SMTP server you want.

Comment: Thanks..... You mean I need to SMTP plugin when i working locally. when I upload my site on live server i don't need to use any plugin for SMTP mail ??? In live wp_mail() works without plugin ???

Comment: Make sure you configured the plugin with the right settings, mostly regarding SMTP server

Comment: Now i am getting "Slow down cowboy, no need to check for new mails so often!". After wp-mail.php file included.

Comment: this is my cron file which is in root directory. Do i need to include wp-mail.php file ?

Answer (score 1):

If you not want to use any plugin to setup your smtp you can do it easy with code . WordPress have their own hook to setup smtp.

Here is the code.  Simply by adding your Host, Username and Password. You can send email from your local machine.

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer_example' );
function my_phpmailer_example( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();     
    $phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true; // Force it to use Username and Password to authenticate
    $phpmailer->Port = 25;
    $phpmailer->Username = 'yourusername';
    $phpmailer->Password = 'yourpassword';

    // Additional settings…
    //$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = "tls"; // Choose SSL or TLS, if necessary for your server
    //$phpmailer->From = "you@yourdomail.com";
    //$phpmailer->FromName = "Your Name";
}
```

You can learn more about it on [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init)